# Including Javascript in Jquery templates

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

Is it possible to perform javscript operations within the jQuery template markup?

I have a collection of objects for which I only want to show certain information on the first iteration through the template.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = 0; // Counter
</script>

<script id="QuoteTemplate" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">

     {{if x = 0 }}
        // Show Stuff
     {{ x++ }}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

JQuery template itself is any HTML markup, along with any of a set of template tags which enable some very rich scenarios for creating data-driven UI. The current set of tags that are supported in jQuery templates are:

```
- ${...}: Evaluate fields or expression
- {{each ...}}...{{/each}}: Iterate without creating template items
- {{if ...}}...{{else ...}}...{{/if}}: Conditional sections
- {{html ...}}: Insert markup from data
- {{tmpl ...}}: Composition, as template items
- {{wrap ...}}...{{/wrap}}: Composition, plus incorporation of wrapped HTML
```

And for more details and example please visit [here](http://www.borismoore.com/2010/09/introducing-jquery-templates-1-first.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it a bad question. The doc is clear but you have to find it on the ${} syntax.

> ${fieldNameOrExpression}
>   The name of a field on the current data item, or a JavaScript function or expression to be evaluated.

Try `$.tmpl('<p>${a + 1}</p>', {a: 1})` in a console.